# SQL Server Deployment automation with SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), VSTS and AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, continuous-deployment

I wanted to do continuous integration/deployment using Visual Studio, GIT, Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and AWS RDS. These are the steps I have successfully done:

1. Created my DB project in Visual studio and checked it into GIT repository
2. Created a VSTS project for CI/CD
3. Linked my GIT repository to VSTS to do auto-polling every 10 minutes and run the build

Now the last step I am stuck with is to do a release and successfully deploy the build to AWS RDS instance. I have created my release definition, added the Artifacts, Environments with release process and SQL DB deploy details as below:

[image]

The problem is with setting the Deployment Group, It's expecting me to add some Targets.

[image]

How can I add these targets? There is no Add button at first place, even though I tried running the powershell script from the details tab on my local machine or AWS VM as mentioned here: http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2017/06/deployment-groups-in-vs-team-services.html, it doesn't add the target. I did install the AWS tools for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services extension, still, i couldn't see a way to deploy the code to RDS. Also is there any way I can deploy without even adding the target?

Comment: Your AWS RDS is a Microsoft SQL server ?

Comment: Yes my AWS rds is SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Build agent directly without configure deployment group, just add an agent phase in release definition (delete Deployment group phase)

[image]

The deployment group uses build agent too, so you can configure it manually instead of using the provided PowerShell script.

1. Download build agent and extract to a folder
2. Run command line as administrator (and cd to build agent folder)
3. Call `.\config.cmd –deploymentgroup`
4. Specify url, name, deploymentgroupname etc… when it asking.

Comment: Under Release definition I have created my environment, added deployment process and agent phase. I'm wondering how can i connect the agent phase to the deployment group and finally add one more step that actually deploys to my AWS DB ? Also from where can i download build agent ?

Comment: @Srini The same agent can't be used as build agent and deployment agent at the same time, so you need to setup a new agent for deployment group (can be on same machine, the name must different). The agent can be download in agent pool admin page (`https://XXX.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool`, click download link)

Comment: @Srini You can't connect the agent phase to deployment group, just can use agent queue.

Comment: Yes I did configure as the default agent without the --deploymentGroup option, So it doesn't  show up in the mahines tab under the Deployment Groups. Nowr emoving the agent from the server and reconfiguring with deploymentGroup.

Comment: able to add the target agent to the deployment group with this command: .\config.cmd --deploymentGroup --projectName myProject --deploymentGroupName myDeploymentGroup